# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token using js file locally

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am not able to fix this problem. I don't know why it is giving me error.

```
<script src="./js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/index.js"></script>

<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="./js/nivo-lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.isonscreen.js"></script>
<script src="./js/script.js"></script>
<script src="./js/main.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

I checked and file exist in js folder. When i access the webpage i am getting two error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token Bootstrap.min.js :7
and
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token Jquery.validate.min.js :4
```

If I add these two directly from CDN then it is not giving me error.

Comment: Just move the reference to jQuery to the top of the `script` tags. The errors are probably because both of them are trying to access `$`.

Comment: Have you declared the jquery library?

Comment: There may be problems with the ordering of the scripts, but forgetting jQuery would not cause the reported errors.

Comment: Jquery is on top of them. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Pointy i have given all the scripts in question. Please advise about ordering.

Comment: Is there any chance that someone has modified those two files? Just to be sure, can you download them again from CDN, and replace your files with the new ones?

Comment: An "unexpected token" error in a script *probably* means that there's something wrong with the script that comes before it. Or it could mean that your scripts are corrupted. Have you looked at them to see whether the problem is obvious?

Comment: i downloaded them from cdn. it is running fine from cdn. only issue with locally defined.

Comment: You have `jquery-2.1.3.min.js` and `jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js`. I'm not sure if those versions can cause a conflict. @Pointy might be aware. Do you see any other errors in F12 developer tools > console?